# ip_conntrack_max not found

Tags: conntrack, nf-conntrack

I did reconfigure /etc/sysctl.conf

> net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 65536
> net.nf_conntrack_max = 65536
>
> net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 600
> net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 600
>
> net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 90
> net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 90

After sysctl -p, I have received;

> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_max: No such file or directory
>
> net.nf_conntrack_max = 65536
>
> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established: No such file or directory
>
> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established: No such file or directory
>
> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait: No such file or directory
>
> sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait: No such file or directory

I have tried to install ip_conntrack module (sudo modprobe ip_conntrack) but it was not installed. No error just lsmod | grep ip_conntrack gives no output.
I am running Debian Jessie and I installed conntrackd 1.4.2

Comment: Any chance you're on a containerised OS?

Comment: thanks for quick response but no, I am not.

Comment: What about `cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max`?  Can you show command and response **by editing it into your question**?

Comment: It the same of second line (net.nf_conntrack_max = 65536)

Comment: Looks like you've got the paths wrong in `/etc/sysctl.conf`; try removing the `.ipv4` *passim*.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your polite and quick response.
I have figured out the solution by installing **nf_conntrack_ipv4** module